# Let $I$ be a finite set with $|I|=n$ and $\forall i\in I $ let $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: induction

Let $I$ be a finite set with $|I|=n$ and $\forall i\in I $ let $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove by induction

$$\prod_{i\in I} (1+a_i)=\sum_{J\in \mathfrak{P}(I)}\left(\prod_{j\in J}a_j\right)$$

**My doubts:**

a) I think the RHS should be one more.

b) What does $J=\emptyset$ imply for the RHS.

**Note:**

I don't want the induction proof. Just clarification of these doubts.

Comment: When $J$ is the empty set, this will give the term $1$... The product of no $a$'s !

Comment: And I believe this is a "two birds, one stone" deal: Knowing that the empty product is 1 should address part a)

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit But how? Please explain in detail

Comment: With empty set ... what will we need to multiply together ... well, nothing ... so we just get the multiplicative identity element $1$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit But what does $j\in \phi$ mean? Moreover, your proof seems nothing more than hand waving to me.

Comment: Write down the list of element in the empty set ... your list contains nothing ... now multiply them altogether ....

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit How do you get 1?

Comment: We are calculating a product, so implicitly start with $1$ & then multiply the first element & the second & so on. ... In our case we start with $1$ & thats it (no multiplications needed!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55247/discussion-between-user330477-and-donald-splutterwit).